# String equality check

Tags: conditionals, algorithms, strings, ifthenelse, comparison

I want to compare 2 strings and perform different tasks based on their results(using if-else loop)
My code is here:

```
\tab• \hyperlink{new}{New Features, Enhancements, and Changes}\linebreak
\begin{algorithm}
    \if {\SynopsysDocName -eq \SynopsysDocName}
        {print("HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII")
        %\tab• \hyperlink{safety}{Safety-Related Issues}\linebreak
        }
    \fi
\end{algorithm}
\tab• \hyperlink{safety}{Safety-Related Issues}\linebreak 
\tab• \hyperlink{stars}{Resolved STARs}\linebreak
```

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: please provide a test file that shows your issue, it is very hard to understand your code fragment which mostly consists of undefined commands like `\tab` what do you want this to do?

Comment: you can test if `\SynopsysDocName` and `\SynopsysDocName` are the same with `\ifx\SynopsysDocName\SynopsysDocName yes \else no\fi` but you are showing use in an `algorithm` enviornment which is not defined but suggests one of the packages for showing literal code not for evaluating anything, Do you want the text `\if {\SynopsysDocName -eq \SynopsysDocName}` to appear in the final pdf or not?